# How can you automate collecting curriculum vitae data?

Tags: dataset, scraping

I'm doing a machine learning project, for which I need data from thousands of curriculum vitae. For this, I need to collect data from the employees of some 50 specific companies. From each company, I require data from thousands of employees. This data simply consists of what positions they have previously held, and with which company; what qualifications they have (e.g. Computer Science BSc from University of Oxford); and what skills they have.

Initially I thought about using a webscraper on LinkedIn, but this is apparently very difficult for technical and legal reasons.

So what other viable solutions are there?

Comment: For those coming across this a curriculum vitae is basically a resume or CV

Comment: Are you working for these companies, or in contract with them? or are you trying to gain insider information about the employees of these companies? The latter is going to be a legal issue.